# Length of a module is sum of length of modules localization at each associated prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, primary-decomposition

> Let $M$ be an $A$-module with finite length, i.e.,  $\ell_{A}(M)< \infty .$ Also $A$ is a Noetherian ring. Then I want to show that $$\ell_{A}(M)= \sum_{p \in \text{Ass}(M)} \ell_{A_p}(M_p).$$

I was trying to show this if $\text{Ass}(M) $ is a singleton. I couldn't do much. I need some help. Thank you.

Comment: If you localize a composition series at $p$, quotients $A/q$ with $p\neq q$ will vanish, and the others will be unchanged. This shows that the number of times $p$ appears in the series is the length of the localized module.

Comment: I appreciate your hint. It works. Thanks